# Rails/postgres: What is the best way to store list of phone numbers for one user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, hstore

So I am little confused on how to store a list of phone numbers in one column. Here are the requirements:

1. Users can have more than one phone number.
2. Phone numbers have to be unique, so if user A added a phone number that is used by user B then a validation error should be displayed.
3. A default phone number should be selected if the user have more than one phone number.
4. Solution have to be compatible with Postgresql.

I thought up of four possible solutions:

1. HStore: making a `phone_number` field that stores a hash of all the phone numbers. e.g. `{1=>"+1-800-123-1234", 2=>"9237492734", "default"=>1}`. In this case I need to make lot of queries to make sure that a new phone number is unique, for example I need to query `User.where("phone_number @> ('1' => '+1-800-123-1234')")` then check in 2 `User.where("phone_number @> ('2' => '+1-800-123-1234')")` ... etc.
2. Array of phone numbers in one field: `phone_number` will store comma separated phone numbers like "+1-800-123-1234,9237492734". Checking a existing phone number would be easy `User.where("phone_number LIKE '%+1-800-123-1234%'")` but will take a lot of time for the database to pick it up. `default_phone` will be added to the table as well or making the first phone number as the default one by convention.
3. Limiting phone numbers to 3 (which is enough) and creating `phone_number_1`, `phone_number_2` and `phone_number_3` fields. Checking the uniqueness of a phone number will consume 3 queries. Also will require adding `default_phone`.
4. Adding a new table `phone_numbers` (id:integer, user_id:integer, phone_number:string, default:boolean) and setting has_many relationship with User model. Which is not really seducing ... create a whole table for 1 field. But it have fast lookups and will have limitless phone numbers for each user.

Any ideas, hints and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: option 4 is the clean relational way. And you are not creating a table for a "single" column, you are modeling your 1:many realationship between users and phone numbers. The only other (second best) option I'd consider is using an array - but only because of the very effective and feature-rich support of arrays in Postgres

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two tables is the solution to go after. You can potentially have multiple users who can be reached at the same phone number, such as a work number or home number that are landlines.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  -- other bits of information
);

CREATE TABLE phone_numbers (
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users (id),
  phone_number TEXT NOT NULL,
  location TEXT NOT NULL, -- Mobile, home, work
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, phone_number),
  INDEX (phone_number)
);
```

If you really want to enforce the 'each person has a unique phone number and that phone number cannot be used to contact anyone else', just add a UNIQUE constraint to the phone_number column.

Comment: If the values for the `location` column should be limited (which depends on the business requirements) it might also be a good idea have a check constraint or a foreign key to a phone_type table. Otherwise it will be hard to find the "home" phone if one user enters "home", the other "private" the next "personal" for the location value.

Comment: Maybe even consider it a domain constraint.

Comment: Uniqueness constraints on phone numbers are tricky. 1-612-555-1234, 612-555-1234, and so on are the same number. Your best bet is to choose a standard format and convert to that format before saving. More badness: (1) office numbers sometimes include extensions (612-555-1234x201) that you might not be allowed to ignore, and (2) while North American numbers are all one format (NANPA) you might have to deal with "international" numbers.